# C: Expected output

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long x = 0x8ce4b16b;
    long long y = x<<4;
    printf("%lx, %lx, abc\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting
**8ce4b16b, 0, abc... Is this okay?**

However if I change `printf` like `printf("%lld, %lx, abc\n", x, y);`

The output becomes:
**2363797867, ce4b16b0, abc**

Why could have been this behaviour!! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using incorrect format specifier in printf invokes Undefined Behaviour. The correct format specifier for `long long` is `%lld`.

Also make sure that you dont have signed integer overflow in your code because that's UB too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `printf("%llx, %llx, abc\n", x, y);` in my mind. `%lx` for long integer.